# How to check if a process is running using python22?

Tags: python

I need to make a Python2.2 program to check if injector.exe process is started, how ?

```
import win32ui

def WindowExists(classname):
    try:
        win32ui.FindWindow(classname, None)
    except win32ui.error:
        return False
    else:
        return True

if WindowExists("DropboxTrayIcon"):
    print "Dropbox is running, sir."
else:
    print "Dropbox is running..... not."
```

Comment: We're not here to do your research. What did you try, did you fail already, what's not working, did you google?

Comment: I've searched on google, the problem is nothing these is the one I search, I don't want see all process open but scan if there is the X process...

Comment: Well, grab a list of processes, filter on your processname, what's the problem?

Comment: Please add code to the question, not to the comments.

Comment: I've edited with the entire script

Answer (score 0):

In general [here](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-win32/2003-December/001482.html) is a good description of what you are looking for.
Googling helps :)